# Simple jquery selector

Tags: jquery

I want to select span of $(this) element, how i can do it?

i want something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/W28fE/2/

but with one ( $(this) ) span element hover effect, not 3

Comment: It looks like you're just applying the hover too broadly.  Try changing `$(".element-flow").mouseover` to `$("#phoneflow .element-flow").mouseover` to apply it to just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(this).children(':nth-child(1)').

jquery child selector :

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

for your question :

$(this).children('span:nth-child(1)')

or something like this:

```
$(".element-flow").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).children('span').css("display", "block");
    });

$(".element-flow").mouseout(function () {
    $(this).children('span').css("display", "none");
    });
```

Comment: thnx, can i do it for child span tag only?

Answer (score 1):

The example you linked to use a class selector, which matches all elements that have that CSS class.
If you only want it to apply to one element then you need to match by a specific ID:

```
$("#phoneflow").mouseover(function () {
$('#phoneflow span').css("display", "block");
});

$("#phoneflow").mouseout(function () {
$('#phoneflow span').css("display", "none");
});
```

Comment: +1, that works!  Also, good job interpreting the question ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
$(".element-flow").mouseover(function () { 
  $(this).find('span').css("display", "block"); 
});

$(".element-flow").mouseout(function () {
  $(this).find('span').css("display", "none");
});
```

You can see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/W28fE/5/).

Answer (score 0):

Ok your question is very incomplete but;

To select a span it has to have an attribute, a class or an id.

so to select on a class

```
<span class="myspan"/>

$(".myspan")....
```

to select on an id

```
<span id="myspan"/>

$("#myspan")....
```

to select a span from a child element

```
$(this).parent(".myspan")
```

or

```
$(this).parent("#myspan")
```

the event will be mouseOver

so

```
$(".myspan").mouseOver(function(){ //your code here  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$(this).find('span').css(...);
```